# How to define invalid routes or 301 redirects?

Tags: asp.net-core

In core how do we go about defining 301's or invalid routes

Example: https:///admin

Admin isn't a valid route or has a controller, but I want anyone hitting it to be sent instead to https:///admin/dashboard

(or even just throw a 404)

Where is this done now?

Thx,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Url rewriting? https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/dev/samples/RewriteSample/Startup.cs#L18